# Using AsyncPipe programmatically - Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I'm using a component to render table like data, I give it the list of columns, the data, how does the data map to each column, and finally a list of pipes to apply to each column data.

So far so good, only problem is when one of those pipes is the async pipe...

After experimenting for some while, I found out that when the asyncpipe is used on the template the transform method gets called several times. However if I use it programmatically the transform method gets called just once (the time I invoke it).

I guess the reason it's called multiple times on template it's because it's an impure pipe, but how can I handle it programmatically?

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1HRZvGQasZUQkG4z8Wzm?p=info) demonstrating what I just said:

```
@Injectable()
export class AsyncProvider {
  constructor() {}
  
  getById(id: number) {
    // Just some mock data
    return Observable.of({id, times_five: id*5}).delay(1000);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [AsyncPipe, AsyncProvider]
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>Template async pipe</p>
      <p>{{ asyncObj | async | json }}</p>
      <hr>
      <p>Programmatically async pipe</p>
      <p>{{ asyncObjPiped | json }}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  constructor(
    private _provider: AsyncProvider,
    private _async: AsyncPipe
  ) {
    this.asyncObj = this._provider.getById(123);
    this.asyncObjPiped = this._async.transform(this.asyncObj);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Because [AsyncPipe](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts) performs a markForCheck() on a ChangeDetectorRef uppon receiving new values, I also tried the following:

```
export class App {
  constructor(
    private _provider: AsyncProvider,
    private _async: AsyncPipe,
    private _ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) {
    this.asyncObj = this._provider.getById(123);
    this.asyncObjPiped = this._async.transform(this.asyncObj);
    
    setInterval(() => {
      this._ref.detectChanges();
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Without any success :(

Comment: What do you mean with **handle it programatically** what do you want to do?

Comment: @AJT_82 I expect it to behave just as if I use the pipe in the template (see the plunker for details), however, because the way asyncPipe works (src code available here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts) the pipe has to be called more than once for emitting the correct result. This seems to be the reason why asyncpipe is not pure, but I can't figure out either how to "emulate" this non pure behaviour programmatically on the controller, nor I have any idea where in angular code it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some struggling I managed to get some results, here it's what I had to do, for future reference.

First method:
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4YETcMyTT4cGYkdR6gKl?p=preview)

```
export class App {
  constructor(
    private _provider: AsyncProvider,
    private _async: AsyncPipe,
  ) {
    
    this.asyncObj = this._provider.getById(123)
    
    let processPipe = () => {
      this.asyncObjPiped = this._async.transform(new_asyncObj);
    }
    let new_asyncObj = this.asyncObj.finally(processPipe).repeat(2);
    processPipe();
  }
}
```

Note that a new variable (new_asyncObj) is needed because finally seems to return a new object rather than modifying the existing one.
And the repeat(2) after the finally so it will unwrap the promise.

---

Second method:
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/A2naeYDgu4XzKzj5bpBP?p=preview)

```
export class App {
  constructor(
    private _provider: AsyncProvider,
    private _async: AsyncPipe,
  ) {
    
    this.asyncObj = this._provider.getById(123)
    
    setInterval(() => {
      this.asyncObjPiped = this._async.transform(this.asyncObj);
    }, 500);
    
  }
}
```

Recalculate the pipe every 500 ms, simple and effective, even though I was expecting for something better.

---

Final method:
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KAUiGuFAcN5IoivGXQOD?p=preview)

```
export class App {
  constructor(
    private _provider: AsyncProvider,
    private _async: AsyncPipe,
    private _ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private zone: NgZone,
  ) {
    
    this.asyncObj = this._provider.getById(123)
      
    this.zone.onMicrotaskEmpty
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.asyncObjPiped = this._async.transform(this.asyncObj);
        this.asyncObjPiped = this._async.transform(this.asyncObj);
        this._ref.detectChanges();
      });
  }
}
```

Using NgZone and ChangeDetectorRef seems to work aswell, even thought some ugly hacking as calling AsyncPipe twice, to unwrap the value.

---

Anyway, hope it can really help anyone who is getting frustrated at dealing with non pure pipes programmatically!

Any suggestion or better answer still welcome!

Comment: I like the idea of using the async pipe because it triggers OnPush change detection (where manually subscribing does not).  And frequently, you need the observed variable in a method.  Give you an A for getting this to work at all.  That being said ... would be nice if there were a cleaner and better-documented way to do it.